# Using an Input Box to assign value to a parameter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code

```
command_Click()

    rDate = InputBox("MM/YYYY")

end sub
```

When I click the command the input box appears and I input my value. But then I get another pop up asking for the parameter value for rDate.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is rDate defined?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a query that's like

```
Select * 
From SomeTable
Where acolumn = rDate
```

The `rDate` defined in your command_click() sub is not the same thing. That `rDate` is a local variable which has nothing to do with your query.

You likely want to pass your parameter to a query. Let's say your query is called `vikesQuery`. Your command button click code would look like this

```
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("vikesQuery")
If qdef Is Nothing Then
   Exit Sub
End If
qdef.Parameters("rDate") = InputBox("MM/YYYY") 'though there are much better ways of getting your parameter like a textbox on a form
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset
```

Now your query is in a recordset where you can do lots with it. Typically you would show this on a form.

```
Dim frm As Form
DoCmd.OpenForm "vikesForm", acNormal
Set frm = Forms("vikesForm")
Set frm.Recordset = rs 'sets the recordset of the form to the recordset you generated from your query.
```

This last step assumes you have a form set up to accept the structure of this recordset. i.e. textboxes bound to the right columns.